# Problem when exporting pgf/tikz to external image (.pdf, .png)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I want to export one or some couples of images from a .tex file to seperate files in PDF and PNG.

I read the pgf manual v3.1.7a section 52 (External Library) and many posts from our community, also stackoverflow, but none of those worked.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzexternalize% activate

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2) (0,0) -- (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm using Win 10 with TexLive 2020 and TexMaker. The test file is called "teststda.tex".
The error code is

> ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "teststda-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{teststda}\input{teststda}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'teststda-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system
> calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also na
> med 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error
> messages can be found in 'teststda-figure0.log'.

I also tried to compile teststda.tex using CMD (Command Prompt) such as

```
pdflatex -shell-escape D:\teststda
```

but it responds in a way that I don't understand as it keep asking me to re-enter the input file name.

---

Let me updated my question. I tried the same thing with article class but nothing changed! The new MWE in this case is

```
\documentclass{article}
% This file is testart.tex

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize% activate!

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, error code is the same. Looking at the file "testart.log" gives me this piece of info:

> 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -inter
> action=batchmode -jobname "testart-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{testart}
> input{testart}"' ========
> runsystem(pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "testart-figu
> re0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{testart}\input{testart}")...disabled (restricted
> ).

> \openout3 = `testart.auxlock'.

Please help! Thank you in advanced.

Comment: standalone + tikz external lib is buggy, see for example [issue pgf#932](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/932). external lib + article class can be used to create pdfs per `tikzpicture`, then you can execute another command to convert pdf to png.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ: I also tried with a similar file whose named "testart.tex" with the same content but changed the class to article (not standalone). Nothing changes! The error code is still the same.

Comment: Do the first lines of log file contain text `\write18 enabled`?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ: Log file said
"entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled."

Comment: The word "restricted" implies that the `-shell-escape` is not turned on. If you use MiKTeX, try `--enable-write18`, see [its doc](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/miktex-pdftex.html).

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ: after surf the internet again, I found a useful page at https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Write18. Followed the instruction for TexLive 2008, I successfully enable -shell-escape to full access on my lap. Back to use TexMaker to compile and 'voila' the export hook works like a charm. However, in case of standalone file, TexMaker compile it in a strange way: slow in process and then hang up!, but the export file is generated!!!

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Do you want to post an answer?